# Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved error in RTL when using routing in useEffect react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I have tried different solutions to resolve it but none is working. I am using **React testing library** to test the Login component. I have different routes stacked like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Home />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/user" exact component={User} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

This is my Login Component.

```
export const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useEffect");
    history.push("/user");
  }, []);

  return <div data-testid="user-login">In progress</div>;
};
```

I have written test case like this:

```
  it("redirects to /user", async () => {
    testRender(<Login />);
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() =>
      screen.findByTestId("user-login")
    );
    screen.debug();
  });
```

Here is my testRender code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export function testRender(tsx) {
  window.history.pushState({}, "Test page", "/");
  return render(tsx, { wrapper: MemoryRouter });
}
```

When I run the test case for:

```
expect(getByTestId("user-login").textContent).toBe(
      "In progress"
    );
```

It is passing but 'waitForElementToBeRemoved' case is not working (error- 'Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved'). The component does executes the useEffect but **history.push("/user");** is not working it seems. Please let me know if there a better way to test this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is no asynchronous code, there is nothing to wait for. You don't need to use `waitForElementToBeRemoved`. Once the `Login` component is mounted, the route will navigate to `/user`.

`MemoryRouter` is useful for testing routes, it has a `initialEntries` prop to accept an array of locations in the history stack. It isn't tied to an external source, like the history stack in a browser, so `window.history.pushState()` is incorrect.

E.g.

`Login.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useEffect");
    history.push("/user");
  }, []);

  return <div data-testid="user-login">In progress</div>;
};
```

`Login.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import { Login } from "./Login";

describe('Login', () => {
  it("redirects to /user", async () => {
    render(
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/user" exact component={() => <div>user</div>} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
      , { wrapper: ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/login']}>{children}</MemoryRouter> }
    );

    expect(screen.queryByTestId("user-login")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText('user')).toBeInTheDocument();

  });
})
```

Test result:

```bash
PASS  stackoverflow/64506942/Login.test.tsx (22.088 s)
  Login
    ✓ redirects to /user (152 ms)

  console.log
    In useEffect

      at stackoverflow/64506942/Login.tsx:8:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        24.151 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```